# Can Multithread execution lead to status 500?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Is it possible that execution of multiple async task using alarm manager can result into status 500 Internal server error while uploading data.

It works for around 2 hours and suddenly gives 500 out of nowhere.

Comment: Impossible to tell. 500 errors are determined on the server, not in the app. There could be many reasons for a 500 error.

Comment: have you put your async task in broadcastreceiver?

Comment: @KishuDroid yes I have exceuted asynctask in broadcastreciever

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use AsyncTask in Broadcast Receiver because the system can kill your process after returning from onReceive method (if there is no any active service or activity). Proof [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ProcessLifecycle)

Official documentation [recommends](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html#Avoiding) IntentService for such cases (see paragraph about Broadcast Receivers).